# java SQLite не сохраняет строку

Tags: java, android, sqlite

при нажатии на кнопку программа пытается сохранить строки в базу данных. Выглядит это так:

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


        cv.put(DateBase.KEY_IDME,editText.getText().toString());
        cv.put(DateBase.KEY_TO,"k");
        cv.put(DateBase.KEY_DATA,editText.getText().toString());
        db.insert(DateBase.TABLE_CONTACTS,null,contentValues);

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Пора покормить кота!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

    }
});
```

При нажатии всплывает такая ошибка

```
Error inserting android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "null": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO cont(null) VALUES (NULL)
```

Ссылается на эту строку:

```
db.insert(DateBase.TABLE_CONTACTS,null,contentValues);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить?

Comment: почему вы заполняете `cv`, а вставляете `contentValues`?

Comment: исправил, теперь ссылается на эту же строку с новой ошибкой

Comment: `Error inserting to=k idme=Name data=Name                                                                 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "to": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO cont(to,idme,data) VALUES (?,?,?)`

Comment: покажите код таблицы `cont`